# UserInterface not being recognized on custom login

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

> I need to login a user manually by using the username and password and
>   returning json response without using the symfony form.

This is the controller where the login happens I get the username and password as requests

```
use Gabriel\LiveLoginBundle\Entity\LiveUser;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken; 

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/livelogin",name="liveloginroute")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $username = $request->request->get('usrn');
        $password = $request->request->get('pwd');
        $roles = array('ROLE_USER');
        $providerkey = 'livemain'; //firewall name

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $em->getRepository('GabrielLiveLoginBundle:LiveUser')->findBy(array('username'=>$username));

        if(!$user)
        {
            $response = array('usernmae'=>'not_found');
            new Response(json_encode($response));
        }

        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken(
            $user, $password,$providerkey,$roles);

        $this->get( 'security.context' )->setToken( $token );


        $this->get( 'event_dispatcher' )->dispatch(
        AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS,
            new AuthenticationEvent( $token ) );

        $this->container->get('security.context')->setToken($token);

        //success
```

When I try to login this way symfony throws an exception

> $user must be an instanceof UserInterface, an object implementing a
>   __toString method, or a primitive string.

Although my liveUser class is indeed implementing the UserInterface

```
/**
 * LiveUser
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gabriel\LiveLoginBundle\Entity\LiveUserRepository")
 */
class LiveUser implements UserInterface
{
```

I also added the necessary methods that UserInterface requires.

Maybe there's something wrong with my firewall setup?

```
security:
    encoders:
        Gabriel\LiveLoginBundle\Entity\LiveUser: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER]

    providers:
        livemain:
          entity: { class: GabrielLiveLoginBundle:LiveUser, property: username }

    firewalls:
      livemain:
           pattern: ^/
           anonymous: true
```

---

Answer
This is the code on the controller that works

```
    $username = $request->request->get('usrn');
    $password = $request->request->get('pwd');
    $roles = array('ROLE_USER');
    $providerkey = 'livemain'; //firewall name

    $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT u FROM GabrielLiveLoginBundle:LiveUser u WHERE u.username = :username");
    $query->setParameter('username', $username);
    $user = $query->getOneOrNullResult();

    if(!$user)
    {
        $response = array('usernmae'=>'not_found');
        new Response(json_encode($response));
    }

    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken(
        $user, $password,$providerkey,$roles);

    $this->get( 'security.context' )->setToken( $token );

    $this->get( 'event_dispatcher' )->dispatch(
    AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS,
        new AuthenticationEvent( $token ) );

    // Fire the login event
    // Logging the user in above the way we do it doesn't do this automatically
    $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
    $this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);

    //success
    $response = array('i'=>0,'password'=>$password, 'username'=>$username);
    return new Response(json_encode($response));
```

Comment: On which line in your controller is the error thrown?

Comment: By the way, findBy returns an array of objects. I think you should use `getOneOrNullResult()`. Let me know if that works, so I can do a proper answer

Comment: Wow it works, post this as answer so I can select it as best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `$repository->findBy()` an array of objects is returned. In your case you want to find only one (or no) user. In that case you should use:

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT u FROM GabrielLiveLoginBundle:LiveUser u WHERE u.username = :username");
$query->setParameter('username', $username);
$user = $query->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Comment: I have used $userData = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->findOneByEmail($email); but still am getting same error. Do I need to add anything more